# How to push change to gerrit server via http?

Tags: http, push, gerrit

I installed and configured my own Gerrit server.

Now, i want push changes to gerrit server via http.
But i don't know how to configure apache & gerrit.

The url said "gerrite push via http already supported."

http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1355

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found the Answer.

login gerrit-server-host -> settings -> http password -> generate password.

Use the password push changes via http.

Comment: That solved my problem when asked for Password for 'http://itay@localhost:8080': (after trying to run the command: git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master)

Comment: i'm stuck: what exact command did you use to push though http(s) to a gerrit server? I've tried `git push    http://username@code.wireshark.org:29418/wireshark  HEAD:refs/for/master/patchname` with no luck (error 503)

Answer (score 0):

The **Generate Password** button just for push/pull source code, not for login the Gerrit WebUI.

And the Gerrit don`t has account manager system.

- [repo-discuss - Re: gerrit password and web problem - msg#00267 - Recent Discussion OSDir.com](http://osdir.com/ml/repo-discuss/2012-04/msg00267.html)